# QueryTables.Add in VBA Adds Same File Regardless Of Filepath

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

Thanks in advance for the help!

In VBA, I'm using the following code to pull in data from an IQY file stored in Sharepoint (Workbooks.Open was not a great option, due to the "Import Data" prompt):

```
Function getIQYWorkbook(ByVal filename As String) As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Dim IQYFile As String
IQYFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & filename

With wb.Sheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
   "FINDER;" & IQYFile, Destination:=Range("A1"))

    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With

Set getIQYWorkbook = wb

End Function
```

What is so bizzare, though, is that the data that gets pulled in does *not* correspond to the actual file I pass in. No matter what I pass in, one particular IQY file in the Sharepoint folder is downloaded. Which makes it frustrating, as this function is called in a loop that passes in different filenames.

For instance, when I use the following code (notice me setting the filepath to the word "dogs", which is ridiculous), that same sharepoint file is still pulled in.

```
Function getIQYWorkbook(ByVal filename As String) As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Dim IQYFile As String
IQYFile = "dogs"

With wb.Sheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
   "FINDER;" & IQYFile, Destination:=Range("A1"))

    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With

Set getIQYWorkbook = wb

End Function
```

This has persisted across reboots/closing Excel/etc.... it's as if QueryTables.Add is "stuck" in pulling the same file regardless of which filepath I pass in. Any ideas of what's going on?

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you inspect the actual workbook connections what do you see after this?

Comment: Weirdly, I don't see any connections... including in the query builder. Or rather, one connection is there, but it doesn't seem to "contain" anything.

Comment: When it loops, the connections currently are added to entirely different workbooks! (since you see the dim for a new workbook). In any case, even if I pass in "dog" as the filepath on the first go-round, it still pulls the wrong file, which signals that excel is saving this somewhere that's persisting through reboots.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this questions is pretty old by now but I've not seen a solution to this problem anywhere.  I only seen 2 reference total about this problem.

I had the same problem occur. 2 other examples that I have work fine and I test a third that worked fine too.

My conclusion is the SharePoint list is generating a bad or corrupt .IQY file. I've tried various Exports form my SharePoint list and they all fail. So I don't have a solution for it!  My workaround plan to is Power Query in O365 to access the data from an Excel file.  This avoids the popups the .IQY file has.